# how to filter with grep for hours?

Tags: linux, centos, bash, redhat

I have the following log file, I want to cut the file with a grep but I only list the content that occurs from hours 7 to 19.

```
 Oct 11 05:26:56 cuervo sshd[983]: Server listening on :: port 22.
 Oct 11 06:26:56 cuervo sshd[983]: Server listening on :: port 22.
 Oct 11 07:26:56 cuervo sshd[983]: Server listening on :: port 22.
 Oct 11 08:26:56 cuervo sshd[983]: Server listening on :: port 22.
 Oct 11 09:26:56 cuervo sshd[983]: Server listening on :: port 22.
 Oct 11 19:40:38 cuervo polkitd[623]: Loading rules from directory
 Oct 11 20:40:38 cuervo polkitd[623]: Loading rules from directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use regex - [play here](https://regex101.com/r/GZPZda/1):

```
grep -E '^ [^ ]+ [0-9]+ (0[7-9]|1[0-9])'
```

This will match any month, any date, and hours 07 - 19... numeric matching like this is not ideal in grep... because regex isn't great a numeric comparisons...

---

You could use awk:

```
awk '{split($3,x,":"); if ((x[1] >= 7) && (x[1] <= 19)){ print }}'
```

- Split the 3rd field (i.e: the time) by colons (`:`), and store in the array named `x`
- Print the line *only* if the first element of `x` (hours) is between `7` and `19`

If you don't want to include entries from at or after `19:00`, then change `x[1] <= 19` to `x[1] < 19`.

If you *do* want to include entries from `19:00:00`, but no later, then change the condition to:

```
( ((x[1] >= 7) && (x[1] < 19)) || ($3 == "19:00:00") )
```

Comment: awk '{split($3,x,":"); if ((x[1] >= 7) && (x[1] <= 19)){ print }}    or  awk '{split($3,x,":")}; if ((x[1] >= 7) && (x[1] <= 19)){ print }

Answer (score 1):

Not grep, but the meaning is clear

```
awk -F'[ :]+' '7 <= $4 && $4 <= 19' file
```

Comment: (posted without reading Attie's answer, I promise)

Comment: Neat use of `-F` - I didn't realise that could be regex too... :-)